# why i can't get my current location through a button

Tags: android, google-maps, location

what i really need to do is when i press the location button is to get  my current location and display it like an address in edit text without map .. but it keep giving me NULL POINTER EXCEPTION .. why???

```
public class PersonalInfo extends Activity{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    EditText addressnew;
     GPSTracker gps;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.personal_info);
           EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
           EditText mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
           addressnew=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
           Button location=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
           Button send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


           location.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                   gps = new GPSTracker(PersonalInfo.this);

                    // check if GPS enabled
                    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    //enable my location
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    //get location object
                    LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    //to retrive provider
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                    //get current location

                    Location mylocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    //set map type
                    //googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    double latitude = mylocation.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = mylocation.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latlng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);


                    Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, latitude+" "+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    List<Address> addresses;
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(PersonalInfo.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try{
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                        String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                        String cities=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                        Log.e("address",addresses+"");
                        Log.e("address",address+"");
                        Log.e("city",cities+"");
                        Log.e("country",city+"");
                        addressnew.setText("your current location is: "+city+""+","+cities+""+","+address+"");
                        //String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + mylocation.getLatitude()+","+mylocation.getLongitude();

                        //Uri path= Uri.parse(uri); 




                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(PersonalInfo.this, "gps is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

            }
        });
     }

}
```

here is the logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at adapter.PersonalInfo$1.onClick(PersonalInfo.java:60)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3530)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14227)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
```

Comment: post the error or logcat

Comment: ok i will now but please can you remove the un vote?

Comment: it's in this line     googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: Have a look at line 60 in `PersonalInfo.java` class and debug from there. It should show you where the `NullPointerException` is.

Comment: i didn't initilize the google map because i don't have a fragment .. how can i do it without a fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the LocationManager and ask for location updates, use these lines in oncreate();

```
 mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, mLocationListener);
```

and then use this to get current latlong of device..

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        //write your code here
    }
};
```

also dont forget to add required permissions..

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
package com.example.loation;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class GettingLocation extends Activity {

    private Double dbllatitude, dbllongitude;
    private LocationManager myLocationManager;
    private LocationListener myLocationListener;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    private LocationControl locationControlTask;
    private boolean hasLocation = false;
    protected Activity Activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.Activity = this;
        GetLocation();
    }

    private void GetLocation() {

        myLocationManager = (LocationManager) Activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocationListener);
        // getlon.setText("Stop");
        if (!myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            displayalert();
        } else {
            locationControlTask = new LocationControl();
            locationControlTask.execute();
        }
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
            if (argLocation != null) {
                dbllatitude = argLocation.getLatitude();
                dbllongitude = argLocation.getLongitude();
                hasLocation = true;
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle arg2) {}
    };

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private class LocationControl extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Getting Location...........");
            this.dialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    hasLocation = true;
                }
            });
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Activity... params) {
            while (!hasLocation) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ;
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (dbllatitude != null && dbllongitude != null && dbllatitude != 0.0 && dbllongitude != 0.0) {
                try {
                    // Write your address code here
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(GettingLocation.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(dbllatitude, dbllongitude, 1);
                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                    String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                    String cities = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    Log.e("address", addresses + "");
                    Log.e("address", address + "");
                    Log.e("city", cities + "");
                    Log.e("country", city + "");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error:::::::" + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                displayalert1();
            }
        }

    }

    public void displayalert1() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        builder.setMessage("Location not found. Do you want to try again?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                hasLocation = false;
                locationControlTask = new LocationControl();
                locationControlTask.execute();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void displayalert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        builder.setMessage("GPS is turned off ,Please Enable GPS").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

}
```